# Overlapping two images with transparency in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two RGB images, and I want to overlap them into one image, and the process should consider that they are fully transparent and ideally it is better to simulate color addition mode in RGB space.

In MATLAB I have tried `imfuse` function but seems the output is not what I expect.

Comment: How do you know which parts are transparent? Do you have a second image containing alpha-values (i.e. transparency info)?

Comment: The duplicate I've marked has what you are looking for.  The purpose is to transparently place a logo image inside a larger image.  Use that as a base to get you started.